# Is there a way to auto filter the getRequest() params in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I don't really want to call the Zend filter in my code after every getRequest->getParam('x') if I don't have to.  Is there a lazy way of filtering everything inside getRequest magically?

**Edit:** *When I say filter, I mean, escapting tags, cleaning out the XSS, and escaping any sql escape characters.*

i.e:

```
$myVar = $this->getRequest()->getParam('x');
filter the variable, escape sql stuf... etc
```

What's the standard?  How are you doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to deal with your situation.

First of all, you can get all params at once:

```
$params = $this->_request->getParams(); //_request is equivalent to getRequest()
```

So a lazy way to filter all your params would be to use the ***** when declaring your filters, which means all fields, and would look something like:

```
$filters = array('*' => array('StringTrim','HtmlEntities','StripTags'));
$input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters,$validators,$params);
if($input->isValid()) {
     //blah blah blah
}
```

You should read more about the [request](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html) object, as well as [filters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.html), [input filters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) and [validators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html).

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to do it every way.

- use `Zend_Filter_Input` (as noted above by karim79) to filter things to how they should be stored or looked up by (stripping tags with `StripTags`, casting to `Int`, `StringTrim`, etc), validating where validation needed - but not htmlentities since that should probably be done on output to avoid complications in db search, etc.  Fields should be individually flitered/validated in most cases.
- use parameterized queries (`Zend_Db_Select` with ? placeholders) always, or at least use the db escape functions
- escape all output (`Zend_View_Helper_Escape` -> `$this->escape()`) as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

karim79's answer covers grabbing the params in one array.

Generally you shouldn't need Zend_Filter on a per request basis to clean up data.

To prevent XSS you should escape data output in a view:

```
$this->escape($someUserSuppliedData)
```

and when dealing with Zend_Db some methods such as insert and update will quote data for you. When constructing queries manually you can use the Zend_Db functions like [quote](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html#zend.db.adapter.quoting.quote)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he is looking for a way to overload the getRequest() method and then filter inside the new created method the request object.

Check out: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html

Then you can just use the Zend_Filter class or create your own filter class overloading the above..