# set a value in $_post with filter input

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans-7

I'm using Zend framework & NetBeans
NetBeans hints to never access post(or get etc) array directly but through input filter
like this

```
$value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'key');
```

but I can't figure out how to use filter_input to set a value in the array

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'key') = $value;//error
```

any pointers are much appreciated

Comment: You are not supposed to change that array.

Comment: @RenéRoth not the post array, or none of those arrays? session array is getting me the same hint

Comment: As I understand it:  the filter_input() function is to inhibit/avoid the user trying to perform some SQL insertion or similar undesirable activity.   The filter_input() function only reads a value out of an array and strips undesirable character sequences, like '|' and '/'.  It cannot 'set' a value in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Zend Framework, why not use the Request Object to get the parameters?

Take a look at **Zend_Controller_Request_Http**.

If you just want to filter the user input, take a look at this Stackoverflow question:

[Is there a way to auto filter the getRequest() params in Zend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865649/is-there-a-way-to-auto-filter-the-getrequest-params-in-zend)

Guess you will find what you need.

If anything is not clear or you are running into problems, just write your question down.

Have fun!